# How can I correctly use a "Base model" with Laravel to extend getAttribute()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to find a place to add some global behaviour when fields are returned, rather than defining accessors for all the fields in all the models.

This led me to try and create a `BaseModel` class which extends `getAttribute()`. I was under the impression this should be called for each field when querying for a model. However, it seems that it is only called when a specific field is requested.

Can someone help me to understand `getAttribute()` and why it's not called in the first example below? Perhaps there is a better place to define some kind of "global accessor" behaviour as well that I'm unaware of.  Thanks!

Sample model:

```
class Thingy extends BaseModel {

}
```

BaseModel:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
  public function getAttribute($key) {
    Log::alert($key);

    parent::getAttribute($key);
  }   
}
```

Results:

```
return Thingy::find(1);  // Returns all fields, but does not hit getAttribute()

return Thingy::find(1)->title  // Returns and logs only title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute()` will be called when you access a property:

```
$model->title;
```

When you just return the model from your controller it will be converted to JSON. That happens by calling `toArray()` on the model. And this will just not call `getAttribute()` but later directly access the `$attributes` array.

---

Essentially for such type conversions (tinyint to boolean, null to empty string) you can use both methods `getAttribute()` or `toArray()`.

`toArray()` if you're using JSON to send the data to the client and `getAttribute` if you passing the model to a server side view. (if you do both then you need both methods)

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    foreach($array as $attribute){
        // conversions
    }
    return $array;
}

public function getAttribute($key){
    $attribute = parent::getAttribute($key);
    // conversions
    return $attribute;
}
```

Comment: If you need more help, tell me what you want to accomplish and I'll edit my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm essentially trying to add some global behaviour to do things like:

- Convert any fields which are Tinyint 0 or 1 to true/false when returning to UI, or convert any NULL values to empty string